# Make variable value negaitve

Tags: css, calc, css-variables

I am trying to figure out a way to make a variable negative.
I have attempted `right: calc(0-var(--skyve-bredde));` bit it did not work.
This is the variable:

```
#drawer, #burger{
    --skyve-lengde:50%;
}
```

The value will be used in `right` and `width` attributes.
Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: you tried `calc(var(--skyve-bredde) * -1)`? you are using SASS or LESS?

Comment: I am familiar with neither SASS nor LESS. I'm writing the css in an ordinary css document.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Reason for the code in question not working:** (all emphasis within quoted text are mine)

```
right: calc(0-var(--skyve-bredde));
```

The above wouldn't work for two reasons and they are as follows:

- As per [CSS `calc()` syntax](https://www.w3.org/TR/2016/CR-css-values-3-20160929/#calc-syntax) there must be a space before and after the + or - operator.

  > In addition, ***white space is required on both sides of the + and - operators***. (The * and / operaters can be used without white space around them.)
- As per [Type Checking for CSS calc](https://www.w3.org/TR/2016/CR-css-values-3-20160929/#calc-type-checking), 0 is a `<number>` whereas the other value is `<percentage>`. For properties like `width`, `left`, `right` etc, the `<percentage>` takes the `<length>` type and so the below check would fail (as the values are not of the same type) and so the expression will be treated as invalid.

  > ***At + or -, check that both sides have the same type, or that one side is a <number> and the other is an <integer>***. If both sides are the same type, resolve to that type. If one side is a <number> and the other is an <integer>, resolve to <number>.
  >
  > If an ***operator does not pass the above checks, the expression is invalid***.

---

**Solutions:**

- As already mentioned in the above answer and the comment, `calc(var(--skyve-bredde) * -1)` will work and produce the expected output.
- Or ***alternately*** using the same type on either side, like `calc(0% - var(--skyve-bredde))` should also work.

```css
:root {
  --skyve-bredde: 50%;
}
div {
  position: absolute;
  right: calc(0% - var(--skyve-bredde));
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div>Some text</div>
```

---

**Adding a negation symbol before the variable:**

This ***will not work*** if my understanding of the spec is correct. Refer the [second code block under Example 11](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-variables/#using-variables) and the explanation. According to that `-var(--skyve-bredde)` would only become `- 50%` which is not a valid value and would hence result in an ***Invalid Property Value*** error.

```css
:root {
  --skyve-bredde: 50%;
}
div {
  position: absolute;
  right: -var(--skyve-bredde);
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div>Some text</div>
```

Comment: After putting `left: calc(var(--skyve-bredde) * -1);`  it does not appear it equals `left: -50%;`. What am I doing wrong?
*EDIT*
It worked! Thank you!

Comment: @user3774924: Can you please show me a demo so that I can see what is going wrong? I just tried a sample and it is calculating correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't ever used CSS variables like that, but logically just reversing the value should work:

```
right: calc(var(--skyve-bredde) * -1);
```